Name variations for direct deposit
Social security Administration sent me a direct deposit with Celestino O Acellam as my name yet I have Celestino Ongwen Acellam as account name in Uganda, will my payments go through?

Have you asked your bank?

Talk to your bank.
Ask what happens if the names don't exactly match.
If you were making a deposit of a check with a teller, most name discrepancies can be dealt with. I have run into a few issues with the use of a shortened first name when using the webpage to upload a check for deposit. It was handled via phone and the bank making a note in the account.
I am not sure what the bank will do. They could reject it, or contact you, or accept it. In my experience, United States banks and credit unions only, full-middlename vs middle-initial or missing-middle-name isn't a problem as long as the bank has the full middle-name.
